# Generating constraints from a list of variables for use in NMaximize

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, constraints

I have an issue concerning constraints which should be generated dynamically from a list of variables.

Suppose I have an expression which is contained in variable `R` which itself has a varying number of variables in it, like `x[1]*5+x[3]*x[2]`. If I knew the number upfront I would just use `NMaximize[{R, 1 > x[1] > -1 && 1 > x[2] > -1 && 1 > x[3] > -1}, f]` where `f` is a list of the variables `x` constructed by `f = Array[x,n]`, `n` being the number of variables I use.

As others do not seem to have similar problems I assume that this is not the way in which such issues are normally addressed in mathematica... However if there is a way to tackle this problem easily I would be glad to hear about it (otherwise I would also be glad to hear about a way to bypass that whole thing).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re: `"I assume that this is not the way in which such issues are normally addressed in mathematica."`. No, it is pretty standard, you are in the good path

Comment: The response and prior comment are on target. I'll just add that you might as well use weak inequalities e.g. LessEqual, because strict inequalities get replaced by their weak counterparts anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose this is your expression:

```
In[1]:= r = x[1]*5+x[3]*x[2];
```

It is relatively easy to extract a list of variables if you know their base symbol:

```
In[5]:= vars = Union@Cases[r,x[_],Infinity]
Out[5]= {x[1],x[2],x[3]}
```

Now you can call  `NMaximize` with dynamically generated constraints:

```
In[7]:= NMaximize[{r,And@@Map[Greater[1,#,-1]&,vars]},vars]
Out[7]= {6.,{x[1]->1.,x[2]->-1.,x[3]->-1.}}
```

The code `And@@Map[Greater[1,#,-1]&,vars]` specifically answers your question, generating the constraints. You can execute it stand-alone to see them.